# Extending en Excel Forumula cells in row based on a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to find a way to do this. At the moment. I import multiple data sets into the spreadsheet. I have 2 pivot tables set up perpendicular to one another. The top horizontal is all test names, the vertical is a list of dates.

The  dates change based on the number of data points pulled in from the query, thus the range changes constantly.

The data is sorted into these two by using the following code.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet3!$B$4:$B$174=E$3)*(Sheet3!$C$4:$C$174=$B10)*(Sheet3!$E$4:$E$174))>0,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet3!$B$4:$B$174=E$3)*(Sheet3!$C$4:$C$174=$B10)*(Sheet3!$E$4:$E$174)),"")
```

The end effect is that the data sorts into the appropriate data/test pair into this format.

I am running into a problem because I need to be able to extend the affected area for the data sort formula, without extending it indefinitely down the rows.

I attempted to use this VBA Macro, but the intent isn't to pull down the EXACT formula, it is to extend the formula as Excel would extend it, changing the items that are allowed to be changed, such as row and columns to change the data sort criteria.

```
Sub aTest()
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("c4:c" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=Len(B4)"
End With
End Sub
```

This did not work due to it copying the formula down exactly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.FormulaR1C1` method instead I think should do the trick, it should account for offsetting cell references.

```
Sub aTest()
   With Sheets("Sheet2")
      .Range("c4:c" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=Len(R[0]C[-1])"
   End With
End Sub
```

The square brackets make the reference relative, so `"=Len(R[0]C[-1])"` refers to one column before and zero rows down